# PHP PCRE : match braces content

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm trying to replace the contents inside braces on a string with `preg_replace_callback`. Here's an example string :

```
230|321;312|123;{413|333;413|334;413|335};583|221
```

What I want to do is being able to replace what's inside braces (`{413|333;413|334;413|335}`) with something else, but I can't quite figure out how to go as for the `regex expression`. I've tried some but with no results.

Little help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match everything from opening brace to close brace:

```
/{[^}]+}/
```